# How can I make the matrix as in the following image in R?

Tags: r, matrix

[image]

I know that I can make a simple matrix (for example 1->20 numbers, 4,5 rows) using this:

```
x<- array(1:20, dim=c(4,5)); x
```

But I have no idea how to make a matrix similar to the one on the picture...

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix(rep(1:4,4)^rep(0:3,each=4), byrow=TRUE, nrow=4)
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
> [1,]    1    1    1    1
> [2,]    1    2    3    4
> [3,]    1    4    9   16
> [4,]    1    8   27   64
> ```

You can create a function if you want to be able to generate an analogous square matrix with an arbitrary number of rows.

```
power_mat = function(n) {
  matrix(rep(1:n,n)^rep(1:n - 1, each=n), byrow=TRUE, nrow=n)
}

power_mat(6)
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
> [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
> [2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
> [3,]    1    4    9   16   25   36
> [4,]    1    8   27   64  125  216
> [5,]    1   16   81  256  625 1296
> [6,]    1   32  243 1024 3125 7776
> ```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

```
t(sapply(0:3, function(x) (1:4)^x))
```

#### Result

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    2    3    4
[3,]    1    4    9   16
[4,]    1    8   27   64
```

(You can easily verify this matches your matrix)

#### Explanation

Each row of the matrix is the vector `c(1, 2, 3, 4)` raised to the power of the row index (in a 0-based indexing system). So, we just use `sapply()` on the vector of powers to raise `1:4` to each power which will return a matrix. Because `sapply()` would return the results as column vectors, we use `t()` to transpose the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
n <- 4
m <- 4

t(sapply( 0:(n-1), FUN =  function (i){ return(c(1:m)**i) }))
```

where n is the number of rows, and m is the number of columns.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    2    3    4
[3,]    1    4    9   16
[4,]    1    8   27   64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 4
m = rbind(rep(1, n), t(replicate(n-1, 1:n)))
m ^ (row(m) - 1)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1
#[2,]    1    2    3    4
#[3,]    1    4    9   16
#[4,]    1    8   27   64
```